# removing duplicate items from dropdownlist database

Tags: .net

I have generated dropdownlist from database using Entity Framework. I can see my dropdownlist in view but I'm getting duplicate values. How can I remove the duplicate values?

```
controller:

DBEntities db = new DBEntities ();
var a = db.AspNetUsers.Select(h => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = h.Nationality,
                    Text = h.Nationality
                }).ToList();
            ViewData["nationselection"] = new SelectList(a, "Value", "Text");


View:

 @Html.DropDownList("selectedItem", (SelectList)ViewData["nationselection"], "-Selce-", new
    {

        onchange = @"
            var form = document.forms[0];
            form.action='GetEmployeeDetails';
            form.submit();"
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I understand you have duplicate values in your database. In EF u can select a distinct values from a db context.

DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
var a = db.AspNetUsers.Select(h => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = h.Nationality,
                    Text = h.Nationality
                }).**Distinct().ToList();**
```